# Insert text over an image and change the text by hovering the mouse over (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, mouseover, onmouseover, mouseout, onmouseout

I have this HTML code and I want to insert a descriptive text for this image, in the center of it. After that I would like to change the text by hovering over the image. Any thoughts on that? I tried several solutions, but most failed to do that for several images, and not for just one in particular.

```
<div class="col-4 col-6-medium col-12-small">
    <a href="#" class="image fit">
        <img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for such an assignment you don't need javascript

let it browser do for you with #pureCss

(using javascript for manipulating with DOM or changing classes on divs are unnecessary overkill)

you can add whatever animation with higher performance (using css)

```css
.image.fit{
  /* block capabilities, but still next to each other */  
  display: inline-block;
  /* be the parent for position absolute later */
  position: relative;
}

.image.fit .normal, .image.fit .hover {
  /* position of the box */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%;

  /* nice box with padding even for multiline */
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  padding: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #333;

  /* animate fade, rather than blinking */
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.image.fit .normal {
  opacity: 1; /* visible by default */
}
.image.fit:hover .normal {
  opacity: 0; /* not visible on hover */
}

.image.fit .hover {
  opacity: 0; /* not visible by default */

  /* optional position on top (remove, for the same place) */
  top: 5%;   
  bottom: auto;
}
.image.fit:hover .hover {
  opacity: 1; /* visible on hover */
}
```

```html
<div class="col-4 col-6-medium col-12-small">
    <a href="#" class="image fit">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/150" alt="">
        <div class="normal">water</div>
        <div class="hover">you can go tomorrow, tickets available</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="image fit">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/300/150" alt="">
        <div class="normal">rocks</div>
        <div class="hover">Lorem Ipsum: Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</div>
    </a>

</div>
```